# Testing RESTful Web Services (RESTClient) on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, plugins, intellij-idea, rest-client

I was going through the IntelliJ IDEA Plugins where I found this RESTfull Web service testing client

[Testing RESTful Web Services](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/testing-restful-web-services.html)

But I could not get it listed in the Plugin directory of Android Studio. Could you please guide me how to add it to the Android Studio.

Tried searching it with this command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> But could not find it.

I am pointing to the RESTClient which is being mentioned in [this](https://vimeo.com/98922030) video @ 44:25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind.

I found it here [IntelliJ RESTClient](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5951?pr=).

Comment: I am getting a "RESTClient threw an uncaught NoClassDefFoundError" error in my Android Studio (1.5). Were you able to install it successfully?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with the IntelliJ 2016.2. Did you ever find the IntelliJ built-in REST Client? I can't seem to find it but I can find documentation for it. Maybe you found a good alternative?

Comment: Incompatible for anroid studio 2.2.2